# Date function and update back issue

Tags: excel, date

I have a two part issue regarding the same item. I have built a contracts management style system that relies on a userform to populate the worksheet and then another userform to recall the data from that sheet. This bit works perfectly. However, there is a 'start date' and 'end date' part that transfers from the userform to the worksheet.

**Problem 1:**

When the date is entered in dd/mm/yyyy and the 'dd' part is 1-12, it translates to US format for the date. For 'dd' values 13-31, it works fine. I have used format date code and this makes no difference.

**Problem 2:**

On the userform, I have an 'update' command button that overwrites any changed data back to the correct row on the excel sheet. If the date gets updated (i.e. 'end date' extended) this just returns 'FALSE' back to the cell. When I reload the contract back into the userform, it shows 31/12/1899.

Please can anyone help on any of the above?

This is the snip of the code for writing the dates for a new contract

```
ws.Cells(Lastrow + 1, 18).Value = TextBox18.Value
ws.Cells(Lastrow + 1, 21).Value = TextBox19.Value
```

This is the snip of the code for updating from the userform back to the excel sheet

```
Cells(rowselect, 18) = Me.TextBox18.Value = Format(TextBox18.Text, "mm/dd/yyyy")
Cells(rowselect, 21) = Me.TextBox19.Value = Format(TextBox19.Text, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

I have searched many posts on here and none of the things I have tried are any better.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: **Problem 1**: You **must** enter the date in the short date format as set by your **Windows Regional Settings**. That is how Excel know how to **parse** your date entered. (This can be altered if you are **importing** a CSV or TXT file).  Excel formatting is only for **display** purposes.  If you cannot change the WRS, you'll need to develop a different method of date entry.

Comment: **Problem 2**: Insufficient information. The results of your code is exactly what I would expect.  All it is doing is comparing the two dates, and writing a Boolean back to those cells. (and `FALSE`, converted to a date, is the date you are seeing).

Answer (score 0):

For **Problem 1**:

If you know that the TextBox always has a date in UK-style *dd/mm/yyyy*, then YOU should take control of how the cell gets setup rather than relying on Excel to decide.  Try code like:

```
arr = Split(TextBox18.Value, "/")
Cells(1, 1).Value = DateSerial(arr(2), arr(1), arr(0))
Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "dd mmmm yyyy"
```

and assuming that the TextBox gives `10/1/2021`, then the result would be:

[image]

For **Problem 2**:

In some languages:

```
alpha = beta = gamma
```

would "daisy-chain" like:

```
beta = gamma
alpha = beta
```

VBA does not work that way.  VBA sees:

```
alpha = (beta = gamma)
```

and evaluates `(beta = gamma)` as a **Boolean**; `True` if beta equals gamma, otherwise `False`

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much, the date format is now correct and working properly but on using the update, it still returns FALSE.

Comment: Hi, I may have spoke to soon, haha. So, although the FALSE doesn't come up anymore once i removed my formatting, the date is in the correct format going in but does not update back in that format, seems to go back to American again. I have checked the settings and it is on English. Any ideas?

Comment: @Reedy  See my **Problem 2**

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. I managed to fix this problem with your help to the following,

```
Private Sub TextBox18_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
arr = Split(TextBox18.Value, "/")
Dim dtDate As Date
dtDate = DateSerial(arr(2), arr(1), arr(0))
Me.TextBox18.Value = Format(dtDate, "dd mmmm yyyy")
End Sub
```

This cures the issue with the date not swapping to US as the date auto-updates in the textbox to Long Date Format.

The update issue I had to use three seperate input boxes for day, month and year and have VB put them together before updating the cell.

Thanks once again for your help.